# How to serialise a large HashMap without getting a StackOverflowException

Tags: java, object, serialization, hashmap, bigdata

With Java, I Have a database of approx. 1.7 million records which I am loading in memory at the start of the program by manipulating these records into a `HashMap`. Values in this hashmap are objects of a class which also has attributes of another class. The below code is meant for visualization of the classes. the actual code is too complicated and long to post here.

```
public void loadHashMap(){
    globalMap = new HashMap<>();
    val = resultSet.getInt(2);// value from database
    val2 = resultSet.getInt(3);

    Class1 c1 = new Class1(val); 
    globalMap.put(val, c1);

    Class1 c11 = new Class1(val2);
    globalMap.put(val2, c11);

    Class2 c2;
    Class1.date.add(c2);

    // this is repeated for all rows in the database
    //then...
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("file.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    out.writeObject(globaMap);
    out.close();
    file.close();
}

public class Class1 implements Serializable{
    public int Id;
    public List<Class2> date;

    //getters setters and other methods

}

public class Class2 implements Serializable{
    public int Id;
    public Class1 cObj1;
    public Class1 cObj2;

    // getters, setters and other methods
}
```

For faster loading and easier transmission of data, I would like to serialize this hashmap and deserialize it when needed instead of building it up from the database. The problem is that I am getting a `StackOverflowException` when I implement this. It might be due to the heavy recursion when classes are referencing each other. Not sure about this though. How can I get past this error

I know the code and the serialization is working since when I load just 100 records, no such Exception is thrown.

Could it be that appending to the file element by element of the hashMap work? or maybe splitting the hashmap into different serialised files? any suggestions are appreciated.

As requested the below is the stack trace of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1522)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at routing.objects.Road.writeObject(Road.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your code example is missing all the logic to serialize it and the location where you get your exception.

Comment: @hotzst serializing logic is there (writeObject) as already said the code is meant for visualization of the classes only. it is too complex to post here.

Comment: If you get problems with recursion you need to break that recursion, e.g. make the backreferences transient and handle them yourself. What exactly you'd need to do depends on your serialization and deserialization logic as well as the actual layout of your data. But in general recursive data is likely to kill serialization, hence you need to break cycles.

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure it's because of recursion. and If so not sure how I should make them transient.

Comment: Well stackoverflow errors normally occur due to recursion - or you have a _very deep_ hierarchy. In any case more indirect connections should help, e.g. if you'd use the ids of the referenced objects instead of the actual references during serialization (make sure you serialize objects only once though) and reconstruct the references from the ids during deserialization (if there are cycles you'd need a second run over your data and probably some intermediate structures).

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the exception to the question.

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda just added the stack trace. Had to truncate a lot of it cause it is quite long and limit was reached.